# How can I use kable or any other table package as default in Rmarkdown rendering

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am pretty sure that I've seen that it was possible to setup `kable` or some other `Rstudio`-supported table package as **default** when I `rmarkdown:::render` a `Rmd` document.

I cannot find if this is a `yaml` option or something that can be `knitr::opts_chunk$set()`

What I want is to stop having to do

````
```{r}
 table = f()
 table %>% head() %>% kable(table) # or something equivalent so the table is 'nicely' displayed 
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your output format (which you didn't mention). For example, for `html_document`, there is [a `df_print` option](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#data_frame_printing), and you can set it to `kable`.